# How often does the node.js mail-listener poll the email box?

Tags: node.js

I'm looking at this node.js code that sets up a mail listener on an email box that I have specified. It works.

However I want to know how often this polls the inbox in question. That's what I don't know and that seems not to be specified anywhere. So how can I find out what the polling period is? Is it even polling? If not how else does get emails as they arrive?

```
var MailListener = require("mail-listener2");
var mailListenerOptions = {
    username: "myUserName",
    password: "myPassword",
    host:     "myHost.com",
    port:     993,
    tls: true,
    tlsOptions: { rejectUnauthorized: false },
    mailbox: "INBOX",
    markSeen: true,
    fetchUnreadOnStart: true,
    mailParserOptions: {streamAttachments: true}
};


var startServer = function(req, res){
    var mailListener = new MailListener(mailListenerOptions);
    mailListener.on("server:connected", function(){
        // Do something
    });
    mailListener.on("server:disconnected", function(){
        // Do something
    });
    mailListener.on("error", function(error){
        // Do something
    });

    mailListener.start();
    mailListener.on("mail", processEmail);
}

var processEmail = function(mail){
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

mail-listener2 works on the IMAP protocol. It works like your Outlook mail client to receive mails. 
If your mail server supports the [IMAP IDLE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMAP_IDLE) protocol, you should get message notifications from the servers as a "push notification" rather than a response to continuous polling.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: you'll get updates immediately.